# Need to allow users to change Product Quantity on Elementor Menu Cart Widget (Pro)

Tags: cart, elementor

Elementor Menu Cart Widget (Pro) does not allow for the user to change the quantity in the mini cart. It only provides an X button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnkaO.png)

I need a code that will add an +- button for the user to increase quantities.  I would really appreciate your help. I'd prefer using a snippet tool to add code to my website rather than downloading a new plugin.

Comment: This is requred... Waiting for solution!